# How to delete All Keyframes Not on a Marker?

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes, motion-capture, marker

Is it possible to delete any keyframe that is not on a frame with a [`Marker`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html)? I'm editing some mocap fbx's and I've marked each frame at which a particular action starts or ends. Now I'm spending a lot of time deleting everything between the Markers. Is there a way to do this? Is this something that can be handled with an add-on? I code, have used Python enough to know my way around it, but a built-in feature would be great.

Comment: AFAIK there is no build-in feature. And if you know how to code (that's what you stated) it should be easy for you to write a few lines python code which does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that will delete all keyframes from all selected objects except the keyframes where there is a [`Marker`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html). In the following example, I have a Marker on frame 5 and 15. Notice how all keyframes get deleted except those on frames 5 and 15.

[image]

Copy and paste this script into the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) and then select all the objects you want keyframes removed except where there is a Marker then click *Run Script*.

```
import bpy

def frame_has_marker(scene, frame):
    for marker in scene.timeline_markers:
        if marker.frame == frame:
            return True
    return False

scene = bpy.context.scene
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for o in selected_objects:
    data = o.animation_data
    if not data or not data.action:
        continue
    for fc in data.action.fcurves:
        keyframes_to_remove = []
        for k in reversed(fc.keyframe_points[:]):
            if not frame_has_marker(scene, k.co.x):
                keyframes_to_remove.append(k)
        for k in keyframes_to_remove:
            fc.keyframe_points.remove(k)
```

Comment: Hey Harry, that's brilliant, will test and see what I can do with it. Sorry for the late reply – was travelling.